# h263 vs h264 on asterisk

Tags: asterisk, codec

I am confused about H263 and H264. Which is best (bandwidth, quality) to use and why? I am interesting in applying this codec on asterisk sip clients.

Thx.
Appreciate

Comment: Stackoverflow is about programming in general.  You may get better results from SuperUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

H.264 is an advanced video codec as compared to H.263. H.264 is far more efficient on bandwidth with the same video quality. But H.264 is a heavier codec as compared to H.263 and will take much more cpu cycles to decode the encoded stream. If you have enough processing power, go with H.264 only but if you don't have enough processing power, you can go with H.263.

Regards, Vibgyor

Comment: is it free to use? I would like to use h264 codec. In term of licence is it ok if i use it or are there any patent?

Comment: i would like to mention that the application where i am going to integrate the codec is not free, is under a selling licence